# Inner join append if ID match

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Person:

> ID, NAME, AGE, DESCRIPTION, STATUS

Values:

```
1, Casey, 18, A fresh grad, Probation
2, Wedy, 25, Middle career, Approve
3, Stacy, 33, A working professional, Confirmed
4, Steve, 45, Senior Management, Confirmed
5, Goat, 55, Retire, Rejected
```

---

Table Permission:

> PermID, TYPE, VALUE

Values:

```
1, normaluser, can view training 1 and 2
1, probationuser, can view training 3 part 1
2, normaluser, can view training 1 and 2
2, traininguser, can view training 3
2, extradinoaryuser, Wendy can view full training
3, extradinoaryuser, Stacy can view full training
3, superuser, Stacy also can edit full training
3, supertrainer, can create full training
```

---

Trying to achieve:

1. Display full Person table data with 'status' = Approved or 'status' = Confirmed

Output - display Person row id 2,3,4

2. If Match Person ID with Permission PermID, get 'type' = extradinoaryuser or 'type' = superuser, ignore the rest type, merge with Person table data.

Output - append Permission 'type' and 'value' Person row id 2,3

3. If entry have both superuser and extradinoaryuser type, duplicate the entry

Output - Person id row 3 is duplicated as both superuser and extradinoaryuser

Desired results:

```
2, Wedy, 25, Middle career, Approve, extradinoaryuser, Wendy can view full training<br/>
3, Stacy, 33, A working professional, Confirmed, extradinoaryuser, Stacy can view full training<br/>
3, Stacy, 33, A working professional, Confirmed, superuser, Stacy also can edit full training<br/>
4, Steve, 45, Senior Management, Confirmed
```

---

Sql commands(Not working):

```
select Person.id, Person.name, Person.age, Person.description, Person.status 
from Person  
inner join Permission ON Person.id = Permission.PermID 
where Person.status like “Approve”  
   or Person.status like “Confirmed” 
  AND (permission.name = 'superuser' or permission.name = ‘extradinoaryuser’);
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use proper Quotation Marks( `''` ) for string variables :

```
select p.id, p.name, p.age, p.description, p.status 
  from Person p inner join Permission m ON ( p.id = m.PermID )
 where p.status like 'Approve' or p.status like 'Confirmed'
   and (m.name = 'superuser' or m.name = 'extradinoaryuser');
```

P.S. Make sure about the (lower/upper)cases of string values in your tables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This similar command was not working. Seem like only either one permission was append, entry not duplicated if have both 'Approve' and ''Confirmed'. P.S permission table got a list of permission with Permid not found in Person ID, these are to be ignore too.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is use proper quotation marks ("") and permission.name column not exists. use permission.type instead

Build schema:

```
create table Person
(ID int primary key Auto_Increment
, `NAME` varchar(25)
, AGE int
, DESCRIPTION varchar(255)
, STATUS varchar(25) );

insert into person values 
( 1, "Casey", 18, "A fresh grad", "Probation" ), 
(2, "Wedy", 25, "Middle career", "Approve"),
(3, "Stacy", 33, "A working professional", "Confirmed"), 
(4, "Steve", 45, "Senior Management", "Confirmed"), 
(5, "Goat", 55, "Retire", "Rejected");

create table Permission 
(PermID int
, `TYPE` varchar(25)
, `VALUE` varchar(255)
);

insert into Permission values
( 1, "normaluser","can view training 1 and 2"), 
(1, "probation user", "can view training 3 part 1"), 
(2, "normaluser", "can view training 1 and 2"), 
(2, "traininguser", "can view training 3"), 
(2, "extradinoaryuser", "Wendy can view full training"), 
(3, "extradinoaryuser", "Stacy can view full training"),
(3, "superuser", "Stacy also can edit full training"), 
(3,"supertrainer", "can create full training");
```

Correct your query as

First get all user which have a status as Approve or Confirmed and then filter the user permission type as superuser or extradinoaryuser or null for display the user has no permission

```
select * 
  from ( select Person.id
          , Person.name
          , Person.age
          , Person.description
          , Person.status
          , Permission.type
          , Permission.value
      from Person 
      left 
      join Permission 
        ON Person.id = Permission.PermID
     where (Person.status like "Approve" or Person.status like "Confirmed")
        ) t 
 where (t.type = 'superuser' or t.type = "extradinoaryuser" or t.type IS NULL) ;
```

see result in
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5a6be/27

Comment: sqlfiddle make it easier to explain. Thank you for pointing out. This command is missing entry 4 Steve is also 'Confirmed', id 2 is duplicated 3 time instead of 1. Permission type and value should be append to id 2,3,4

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5a6be/9/0 almost there. Person id 4 Steve row is missing. Person id 2 Wedy should only show 1 row with extradinoaryuser type.

Comment: Unless permissionid is primary, I can't really see this working

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your quotes.  However, I would recommend two things for the query:

- Table aliases.
- `IN`

The query would look like:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.age, p.description, p.status 
from Person p inner join
     Permission pn
     ON p.id = pn.PermID 
where p.status in ('Approve', 'Confirmed') and
      pn.name in ('superuser', 'extradinoaryuser');
```

In SQL, the standard string delimiter are single quotes.  These should be used for defining string and date constants (and not for other purposes).